# VS 2017 builds x64 project with cross compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake

I have a huge project in c++ for which i use cmake to generate the the .proj files.

Using CMake version 3.12.2 which supports generation of VS2017 proj files.

So for windows 64 bit compilation i use the following generator

`CMAKE_GENERATOR="Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`

This creates a .proj file at build time and is used to compile.

But from build logs what i found is that the visual studio compiler cl.exe is taken from cross compilation location

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
```

/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe is being used.

But i want it to be built strictly using x64 compiler. From /Hostx64/x64/cl.exe

I have read from other questions where people have mentioned to add few tags to the .proj file to force vs to use x64 compiler.

But how do i do that withe cmake file ?

I did not find any reference with this regards except the cmake generator mentioend above.

Could anyone please help me how to use cmake to strictly make VS use x64 compilor?

Note: I want it to be built with x64 compiler because i am linking to the boost library which is also compiled with

```
address-model=64 architecture=x86
```

And while the main project is compiled i am getting platform related errors.

```
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

That's why i wanted to compile the main project with x64 compiler.

And also, whats the difference between Hostx86/x64/cl.exe and Hostsx64/x64/cl.exe ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the nature of the "Host x86, target x64" compiler. It definitely creates x64 modules, not x86 modules. I suspect the linker errors are caused by putting x86 and x64 output in the same directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a usual "problem". By default CMake will pick up the 32bits compiler, which is usually fine, except for projects like LLVM.

Use `-T host=x64` (see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.html) to use the native 64bits compiler.

Note that the last entry in the path is the target platform, not the host platform, so both the 32bits and the 64bits compilers will produce 64bits code.

Comment: so it would be like CMAKE_GENERATOR="Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -T host=x64 ??                                 There are no examples and its quite confusing what they are saying.

Comment: I think so, yes. Usually I'm using the GUI on Windows, and there is just one place where to put this option.

Comment: I have added the following values in our script.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM="Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
   CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET="v141_xp host=x64"
   CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_HOST_ARCHITECTURE=x64

But still the compiler used is

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe

Comment: Did you start from scratch (empty build folder)?

Comment: Yes, we have a build system we deletes the entire folder before starting.
Could there be some problem with the way i have built boost library ? i had built boost library 1.53 with vs2k17 toolset, which that version of boost doesn't support. But i managed to change some header files and get the libs.

Comment: Boost intervenes after the compiler detection. The additions for your script are done with -DCMAKE_xxx I suppose?

Comment: adding -Thost=x64 in the cmake command instead of setting flags worked. thanks @matthieu

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem as described in the OP.

I think the explicit (and in my opinion recommended) way to set the build system, compiler, architecture, toolset and Windows SDK on a Microsoft Windows operating system is to use the following CMake command line arguments:

```
-G "Visual Studio 15 2017"
-A x64
-T v141,host=x64,version=14.12.25827
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=cl
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=cl
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION:STRING=10.0.16299.0
```

This sets the compiler executable as follows on my system:

`%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\`**Hostx64**`\`*x64*`\cl.exe`

The `-A x64` argument sets the italic part in the file path above and the `,host=x64` part of the `-T` argument sets the bold part.

It's also a good idea to explicitly set the toolset, both the major version (`v141`) and the minor version `,version=14.12.25827`.

According to the official CMake documentation the `"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` generator is there only for compatibility with CMake versions prior to 3.1. I suggest to not use the `"[...] Win64"` generators any longer in general.

Sources:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET.html